# How to Grant Access Rights/Permissions to specific sheets/data connections of an Excel document?

Tags: excel, permissions, access-rights

I want to be able to create one Excel workbook - but limit read access to certain worksheets and/or ability to refresh certain data connections. I am using SQL data connections to drive the worksheet.

Is there any way to do this with Excel? I am open to any method to make this work!

Comment: What criteria are you looking to restrict the access on. You could use VBA to prevent certain actions based on the users windows logon id using `ENVIRON("USERNAME")` variable

Comment: Thanks for replying, looking to restrict access to specific areas to users on a username and password list?